# Frequency distribution of a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, variables, frequency

I am trying to prepare a frequency distribution table of  a categorical variable in my data and I am using below code. But the output looks ok while I view it but not printing ok in report.

```
# These lines are not needed because the data below is already
# in that format
# STI<-STI_IPD1%>% select(Q18_1,Q54)
# STI$Q54<-as.factor(STI$Q54)

STI = structure(list(Q18_1 = c(101L, 120L, 29L, 101L, 94L, 16L, 47L, 
141L, 154L, 47L, 141L, 154L, 154L, 29L, 58L, 154L, 101L, 154L, 
47L, 141L, 75L, 1L, 120L, 16L, 154L, 141L, 141L, 154L, 154L, 
154L, 29L, 141L, 38L, 47L, 101L, 16L, 154L, 154L, 101L, 192L, 
58L, 154L, 16L, 120L, 101L, 1L, 38L, 1L, 154L, 1L, 16L, 58L, 
75L, 154L, 47L, 58L, 120L, 141L, 1L, 141L, 16L, 141L, 58L, 29L, 
101L, 58L, 154L, 75L, 75L, 141L, 29L, 101L, 101L, 154L, 16L, 
101L, 101L, 47L, 47L, 181L, 16L, 154L, 47L, 154L, 47L, 120L, 
75L, 47L, 192L, 1L, 154L, 154L, 120L, 141L, 58L, 47L, 154L, 101L, 
75L, 141L, 75L, 16L, 47L, 1L, 58L, 141L), Q54 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Discretionary if earnings per share goals are met.", 
"initial funding by targets and as year goes on begin to include financial results", 
"Non-represented are targets focused and budgeted and union plans are self funded based on operating margin achievements."
), class = "factor")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-106L), .Names = c("Q18_1", 
"Q54"))

as.data.frame(table(STI$Q54))
```

Is there any other way to prepare such outputs?

I want output as a table of counts of each factor level. each factor level in one column and  and counts in another column.

I am taking output in word file using Rmarkdown. Also in the output window the output is not printing as two columns table.

Comment: Not clear what you're expected output is. Can you append your question to include the expected output/plot as an example? Do you mean something like a barplot, e.g. `barplot(table(STI$Q54))`? On a different but related note, you might want to give more sensible (i.e. shorter) factor levels for `STI$Q54`. Also, most entries in that column seem to have factor level `""`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by not printing ok in the report? Are you trying to copy it to a word document, or are you using Rmarkdown + knitr? A screenshot showing the problem would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added my requirements. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @Mayrits Evers, yes the factor has many " ", the variable has many null values and I want to summarise this categorical variable for the values and their counts. These are statements for a given question, I can't shorten these.

Comment: Please tag users you reply to (e.g. @phil) as we don't know you've replied otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a data frame as a table in Markdown, one can use the `kable()` function in `knitr`.

```
library(knitr)
kable(aDataFrame)
```

For example...

[image: Sample Rmd HTML]

`data.frame()` with the `kable()` function is really useful technique for communicating tabular information in R Markdown. For a couple of more complicated examples using this technique, please read my article [Commentary on ToothGrowth Factorial ANOVA](http://rpubs.com/lgreski/toothgrowthanova), where I compare Robert Kabacoff's analysis to the requirements of the Johns Hopkins University Statistical Inference course on Coursera.

regards,

Len

**(11/22/2017) UPDATE:** Responding to a comment from @sandhya-ghildiyal , here is how to exclude the blank row from the table output. If we save the result of `table()` into an object, we can then use the extract operator `[` within the `kable()` function to exclude the row where the factor value is 1, the blank space.

```
theTable <- as.data.frame(table(STI$Q54))
kable(theTable[as.numeric(theTable$Var1) != 1,])
```

Comment: Thanks Len, this was really useful. I will try using this for couple of other outputs also.

Comment: Now there is one more thing I am trying with this output is to remove the blank cell and its frequency 103. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Hello @sandhya-ghildiyal . Please see the edits to the original post that answer the question you posed in your comment. Also, please upvote the original answer if you found it helpful. Thanks!